# Building an App that controls my math courses

Tags: javascript, python, android, ios, django

I am a mathematician who has programming skills. I have a (Math) YouTube channel and give paid math courses. I want to build (or adjust a template of) a web application that allows me to control access to my classes (private playlists on the youtube platform). I will authorize the customers who have already paid to see the courses. Is there a known way to do that? I will be grateful for any suggestions and enlightenment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something, would you like to show only a form to submit by students on site?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I want to control which student can access and which one can not. Just the students who paid can access.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for suggestions for some kind of template to work/edit anything for yourself but have you ever considered using Udemy? It's great for posting your course/classes where only people who have already paid for your course, have access to it.

Comment: I know about Udemy, but I want to make my own simple app.